# TNS-12500: TNS:listener failed to start a dedicated server process Oracle9i Database on Windows 2003 64x server

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i, listener

My client wants to move his database from Windows 2000 server to Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition 64x server. I have created the Windows servers in VMware and installed the Oracle 9i databases on it. When I try to connect to the database Oracle 9i installed on Windows 2003 using sqlplus, using the System account on the same Windows Server 2003, it is giving following error in the listener.ora log file:

```
12-JUN-2015 23:30:55 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=HRPRD)(SERVER=dedicated)(CID=(PROGRAM=E:\APPS\ORAHOME\bin\sqlplusw.exe)(HOST=PEOPLETECH-2003)(USER=PSOFT))(SERVER=dedicated)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.59)(PORT=3348)) * establish * HRPRD * 12500
TNS-12500: TNS:listener failed to start a dedicated server process
 TNS-12546: TNS:permission denied
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00516: Permission denied
    32-bit Windows Error: 5: Input/output error
```

TNSNAMES.ORA entry is:

```
INST1_HTTP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.59)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = SHARED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MODOSE)
      (PRESENTATION = http://HRService)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

HRPRD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.59)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = HRPRD)
    )
  )
```

Listener.ora entry is:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      )
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.59)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\APPS\ORAHOME)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = HRPRD)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\APPS\ORAHOME)
      (SID_NAME = HRPRD)
    )
  )
```

I have read many blogs on the forum, tried:

1. uninstalling and installing Database again,
2. tried changing the SID using oradim utility.
3. Added environment variables TNS_ADMIN,ORACLE_SID,ORACLE_HOME

I am not able to figure out the problem. Even if Windows 2003 support has ended or Oracle higher versions are available still as its my client's environment its his Requirement for which I need it to make it work on Windows 2003 EE 64x, no option.

Comment: `TNS:permission denied` - check the Windows users that are used to start the database and listener service. Also disable UAC if that exists on 2003.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mat. I am using user which is the part of Administrator group as well as I used Administrator user itself. I was troubleshooting on it further and I notice that when in the installation process itself when the installer tries to install the

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mat. I used Administrator also. I was troubleshooting on it further and I notice that when in the installation process itself when the installer tries to install the Database Configuration utility I get the TNS adapter error and logs error to  sqlnet.log is generated with below Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle)(ARGV0=oracleHPRD)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))'))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=HPRD)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\ora92\bin\sqlplus.exe)(HOST=DSMANE-5758FECF)(USER=Administrator))))

Comment: Issue Resolved. Disable the Anitvirus & Windows Firewall.  After setting all varaibales as defined in the Installation doc, following all network protocols  when finally I disable the Antivirus it worked like a charm ... Thanks to all help .. This is my first post and liked overall experience